# How do I kill a process in Linux without using kill?

Tags: linux

I am supposed to kill job #3 without using the command `kill %3`. How do I do that? I can’t seem to find the answer anywhere. I can only use *one* command. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: not really the right site for this but since I'm here, you can use `top`, hit `k` and then type the `PID` in.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Title says "without using kill" but the description says without using "kill %3". There is a difference. For example, you can use kill with the process id rather than a job number. But it's not clear from your question whether that is acceptable or not.

Comment: You could do a `ps` and find the PID and use kill -9 PID.

Comment: I am only told that I have to terminate job #3 assuming the command "kill %3" didn't work. I have to terminate it with only one command.

Comment: Type `help jobs` at the `$` or `#` prompt. Then type `jobs -l`. If there are no jobs, that's why it won't work.  If there are, try `kill -9 <pid>` for job #3 if it's there. If there aren't three or more jobs, were you supposed to start three jobs in the background first?

Comment: Who is asking you to do this? Why?

Comment: It's a review question in a textbook.

Comment: "killall <process_name>" is another option. Of course that has the side effect of killing all processes with that process name. But hey, your question still doesn't specify the problem parameters clearly so what is not specified is allowed :-)

Comment: Also pkill  http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill

Comment: If it's a review question in a textbook, then the only way to find the specific answer they're looking for is to read that chapter of the textbook.

Comment: @ Charles Duffy Actually I have read through this entire chapter and there is not mention on how to kill one particular job about how to kill a job without doing "kill %3" in one command. I read through the textbook which is why I am here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's a review question in a textbook.

It's fairly easy to find textbooks, and other documents, talking about `kill %3`.  And where they do, it is fairly obvious what this question is getting at.  It's not getting at alternatives to the `kill` command.  It's not getting at using process ID numbers instead of shell job specifiers.  It's getting at this:

> To terminate a running program in the background, type `kill %n`, where `n`is the job number you want to terminate. For example, typing `kill %3` terminates job number three. Some programs need more than the `kill` command to be terminated. Strengthen the killing power of the `kill` command with this syntax: `kill -9 %n`

— Brent D. Heslop, David Angell (1990).  *Mastering SunOS*. Sybex. p. 189

It's getting at the fact that *sometimes `SIGTERM` doesn't work*.  So, on the assumption that it hasn't worked (because the process has caught and handled the signal without terminating), you need to try sending some different signals.  Books give the answer to that, too:

> A good general rule is to try `TERM`, `INT`, or `HUP` signals first to stop a process. If they fail, then use the `KILL` signal.

— Robin Anderson, Andy Johnston (2002).  "Day-to-day system management". *Unix Unleashed*.  Sams Publishing. ISBN    9780672322518.  p. 404.

### Further reading

- ["`kill`"](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afsk#kill). *Introduction to Unix commands*.  Indiana University.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19475/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/
- [*Useless use of `kill -9`*](http://novosial.org/shell/kill-9/index.html).  Peter N. Steinmetz.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple command, if you want to kill a background job by `kill` would be:

```
kill $(jobs -p 3)
```

`-p` lists only pids, and the number 3 is the jobspec.

Comment: Oh. That's a bit simpler than mine. I should read the help pages before answering...

Comment: @tripleee made the edit =)

Comment: In typical linux shells, `kill` and `jobs` are both commands, so this doesn't meet the stated requirement -- "I can only use one command".

Answer (score 1):

You can always `fg 3` (foreground job #3) and then cancel it with Control-C or whatever the normal method for exiting the command is.

Comment: Perhaps not the sought answer, but pretty straight thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Review questions are meant to make you think; they're not much good if the answer is written out explicitly in the chapter body.  What else do you know about the job?  Do you know its name?  Do you know it was the most recently started job?  If *all* you know is that it's job number 3, clearly you have to reference it that way somehow.

There are several ways to refer to jobs other than by their number; from [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> There are a number of ways to refer to a job in the shell.  The character `%` introduces a job name.  Job number `n` may be referred to as `%n`.  A job may also be referred to using a prefix of the name used to start it, or using a substring that appears in its command line.  For example, `%ce` refers to a stopped `ce` job.  If a prefix matches more than one job, bash reports an error.  Using `%?ce`, on the other hand, refers to any job containing the string `ce` in its command line.  If the substring matches more than one job, bash reports an error.  The symbols `%%` and `%+` refer to the shell's notion of the current job, which is the last job stopped while it was in the foreground or started in the background.  The previous job may be referenced using `%-`. In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command), the current job is  always flagged with a `+`, and the previous job with a `-`.  A single `%` (with no accompanying job specification) also refers to the current job.

Here's a [table of the job name options](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html#JOBIDTABLE), if that's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pkill` (or) `killall` function

Comment: This has the distinct disadvantage of potentially killing a large number of unrelated processes.  If you do `sleep & sleep & sleep` then `killall sleep` will kill all three, not just the third (and indeed, there is no way to single out one of the jobs).

Comment: @tripleee And not only these three, but also others which might have been run by a cron job, maybe for good reasons...